# How to set the time zone with php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set the time in PHP, but I don't know to set the time zone.

```
<?PHP 
   $currentDateTime = time();
   $newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($currentDateTime));   
?>

<input type="text" name="time" value="<?php echo $newDateTime; ?>"></input>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
echo date('H:i:s', time());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
?>
```